# Make left-aligned div to take up all space

Tags: html, css, position

I want to make a guide to run a command in `Windows command prompt`.

```
.bold-cli {
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px 30px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
}

<div class="bold-cli">
    C:\> Rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache 
</div>
```

I want the `div` to take up only space enough to show the command, instead of stretched horizontally, so I add `float: left`.

The problem is, the content after this div does not start with a new line, it is displayed on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `clearfix` div  as shown below to remove the float affecting the next element.

```css
 
.bold-cli {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.clearfix::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="bold-cli">
 ABC ABC  ABC ABC  ABC ABC  ABC ABC  ABC ABC  AB ABC  ABC ABC  ABC 
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>

Start from new line
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bold-cli {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>To fix this, start a command prompt, type the following command and then press Enter.</p>
<div class="bold-cli">
  C:\> Rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache
</div>
<span style="float:left;clear: both;">We have build a utility to run this command for you. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: #DB5523;">Click me</a></span>
```

Comment: but then the black box takes up all space. That is what I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: nice, that i do not noted